# Determine the induced distribution for $|X|$ when $X$ is standard normal

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that $X \sim N(0,1)$ - i.e., it is of standard normal distribution. I need to determine the induced distribution for $|X|$.

According to my text, if an r.v. $X$ has distribution $\mu$ and $g: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, then, for $Y = g(X)$, $$ P(Y \in A) \equiv P(g(X) \in A) = P (X \in g^{-1}(A)) = \mu(g^{-1}(A)) = \mu g^{-1} (A) $$
where $A$ is a Borel set.  Thus $Y = g(X)$ has the **induced distribution** $\mu g^{-1}$.

Here, $g(X) = |X|$, but the absolute value function doesn't have an inverse in the usual way - you'd need to consider it piecewise, say for $x < 0$ and for $x \geq 0$, so how do I express this here? Also, I know that $\mu(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{x}e^{-t^2/2}dt$.

So, after I have figured out how to properly express $g^{-1}$ here (which I'm hoping you can help me with), how do I put it together with $\mu$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in order to directly address the point where you're stuck, note that in this context $g^{-1}$ refers to computing preimages rather than inverting the function: $|X|$ only takes nonnegative values, so it is sufficient to consider $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^+)$. Then 
$$g^{-1}(A)=A\cup(-A)$$
and due to symmetry of $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$
$$\mathbb{P}(|X|\in A)=2\mathbb{P}(X\in A).$$
In order to explicitly describe the distribution, take $x\geq 0$ and observe
\begin{align}\mathbb{P}(|X|\leq x)&=2\mathbb{P}(0\leq X\leq x)\\
&=2\left(\mu(x)-\mu(0)\right)\\
&=2\left(\mu(x)-\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
&=2\mu(x)-1.\end{align}
This fully describes the distribution. You could also obtain the pdf through differentiation.

Comment: see my comment to the other answer below. Are we on the same page there?

Comment: Yes, you just forgot to take the square root.

Comment: yeah that was silly of me. Thanks.

Comment: one last thing I'm not sure about is where the $2 \mu(x) - 1$ comes from. Could you explain that a bit?

Comment: Yes, I added more details. The main ingredient is $\mathbb{P}(X\leq 0)=0.5$.

Comment: thank you! You're the best!

Comment: and so $\mu(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{x} e^{-x^2/2}dx$? (Just making sure)

Comment: That's very nice of you to say - I'm glad I could help!

Comment: The distribution of $|X|$ is given by
$\widetilde{\mu}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^{x}2e^{-t^2/2}\mathrm{d}t,~x\geq 0$.
The factor 2 is very important, it reflects the fact that negative and positive values are "folded" by the absolute value.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't answer right away, but the answer given is very good. Anyway, I'm glad you asked me directly, that's a nice compliment!

Comment: Sorry again, I can't do this properly now, but I added a comment at least.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't taking the inverse in the usual sense; you are looking at the inverse of a set, so the inverse of (1,2) will be $(-2, -1) \cup (1,2)$. You can now find the inverse of any set of the form $(-\infty, x)$; think of what happens when $x < 0$, and $x > 0$. I am not sure how much you can simplify it, but if your final answer is allowed to be in terms of $\mu(x)$, then it looks like a very reasonable expression.

Comment: when $x<0$, the inverse of $|x| = -x$, when $x>0$, the inverse of $|x| = x$. Is that what you mean by "think of what happens when $x<0$ and $x>0$"?

Comment: then would it be something like $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-x}^{x} e^{-x^2/2} dx$?

Comment: The inverse would the empty set when $x < 0$; think of the functions more like mapping sets to sets as opposed to numbers to numbers.