# Induced Distribution of the truncation $X\mid (X>0)$ with $X$ standard normal

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I need to determine the induced distribution of the truncation $X\mid(X>0)$ with $X\sim N(0,1)$ -i.e., $X$ is a standard normal variable with mean $0$ and variance $1$.

I'm not all that familiar with the idea of truncated distributions, so I read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution) article.

From the article, I determined that if $N \sim N(0,1)$, then $$f(x\mid X>0) = \frac{g(x)}{1-\Phi(0)} $$
where $g(x) = f(x)$ $\forall x >0$ and $=0$ everywhere else, and $\Phi(0)$ is the cumulative distribution function $$\Phi(0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-t^{2}/2} \, dt = \frac{1}{2}.$$

So, $$f(x\mid X>0) = \frac{g(x)}{1-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{g(x)}{\frac{1}{2}} = 2 g(x).$$

Thus, the probability density function for the $X$'s we are interested in is given by $2g(x)$.

Now, I did a similar problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2508699/determine-the-induced-distribution-for-x-when-x-is-standard-normal). but I am not sure how to apply something similar to this problem. All I've done thus far is find the pdf for the truncated variable, now how do I find the induced distribution? Could somebody please help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: i thought the induced distribution *is* characterized by the pdf

Comment: @gt6989b According to my text, if an r.v. $X$ has distribution $\mu$ and $g: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, then, for $Y = g(X)$, $$ P(Y \in A) \equiv P(g(X) \in A) = P (X \in g^{-1}(A)) = \mu(g^{-1}(A)) = \mu g^{-1} (A) $$
where $A$ is a Borel set.  Thus $Y = g(X)$ has the **induced distribution** $\mu g^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As gt6989b implies in the comment, you have for all intents and purposes already found the induced distribution. It sounds like what you want is to put the induced distribution into the form you describe in your comment responding to them.

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb R_{\geq0}$. Then where $X$ is your truncated normal r.v., $f_X$ is its pdf which you have already found, and $f$ is the standard normal pdf:
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X\in A) &= \int_A f_X(t)\,dt\\
&=\int_A2f(t)\,dt\\
&=2\int_A f(t)\,dt\\
&=2 F(A)
\end{align}
where $F(A)$ gives the measure of $A$ under the standard normal distribution, ie $F(A)=\int_A f(t)\,dt$.